# How to set array elements to dynamic created Textview in android

Tags: android

How to set array elements to dynamic created textview in android

**MainActivity1 :**

```
public class MainActivity1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    public String Message;
    public String[] mobileArray;
    int len;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        mobileArray = editText.getText().toString().split(",");
        len = mobileArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);

        TextView[] tv = new TextView[len];

        for (int i = 0; i <=len; i++) {
            tv[i] = new TextView(getBaseContext());
            tv[i].setText("" +mobileArray[i] );
            tv[i].setPadding(50, 50, 0, 0);
            tv[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));
            rl.addView(tv[i]);

        }
    }

}
```

How to set array elements to dynamic created textview in android

Here everthing works fine, it creates dyanmic textview. But i need to display the array elements in textview.

When i try to set the array element app stops working.
Please help me.

This my edit code

and my log cat is

```
      12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779): Process: com.example.new_word, PID: 2779
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):     at com.example.new_word.MainActivity1.onClick(MainActivity1.java:56)
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-26 02:13:44.897: E/AndroidRuntime(2779):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 02:13:47.467: I/Process(2779): Sending signal. PID: 2779 SIG: 9
```

Xml code is

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: pls declare textview with. TextView[] tv = new TextView[len];

Comment: what is the value of len??

Comment: length of mobileArray

Comment: yeah but what is the value of len??

Comment: len should be 2 or 3 like that

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below:

```
 if(!(editText.getText().toString().equals(""))){

      TextView[] tv = new TextView[len];
      for (int i = 0; i <len; i++) {
        tv[i] = new TextView(getBaseContext());
        tv[i].setText(mobileArray[i]);
        tv[i].setPadding(50, 50, 0, 0);
        tv[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        rl.addView(tv[i]);
        }

  }
```

Comment: @user3133954 are you getting any Exception?

Comment: have you get all elements in mobileArray element.??

Comment: 12-26 01:13:26.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1468): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: `@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  LinearLayout rl = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear1);
  
  TextView[] tv = new TextView[50];
  
  for (int i = 0; i <len; i++) {
   tv[i] = new TextView(getBaseContext());
   tv[i].setText("" + mobileArray[i] );
   tv[i].setPadding(50, 50, 0, 0);
   tv[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));
   rl.addView(tv[i]);
   
  }`

Comment: ohhkk. that the problem of len value.. check my answer now.. put len into textview array instend of 10.

Comment: @User3133954 what is line number 56??

Comment: @Segi i post that too

Comment: if i enter like Android,Windows,Iphone. It should split it and display in one by one in textbox

Comment: @Segi This my Question if i enter like Android,Windows,Iphone. It should split it and display in one by one in textbox continously

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
TextView[] tv = new TextView[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    tv[i] = new TextView(this);
    tv[i].setText(mobileArray[i]);
    tv[i].setPadding(50, 50, 0, 0);
    tv[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000")); 
    // tv[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    rl.addView(tv[i]);
}
```

here you have used the color #000000 which means a transparent color. thus you are unable to see the Text

Comment: are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException still? or which exception?

Comment: when i cilck button it stops working Log cat error  java.lang.NullPointerException  android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

Comment: so your mobileArray is null

Comment: i spit the string with comma and store tat in mobilearray

Comment: either your LinearLayout **rl** is null or text in EditText is empty

Answer (score 0):

The first error that i can point is in your for loop condition:[Change it too]

```
for (int i = 0; i <len; i++)
```

if the error still persists then please post your logcat;

Also change this code to display the text at that array:

```
tv[i] = new TextView(getBaseContext());
        tv[i].setText(mobileArray[i]);
```

Comment: your condition is i<=len which will definitely give a ArratIndexOutOfBound exception; try changing that condition. ALSO MAKE SURE YOU ARE NOT ADDING MORE THAN 10 TEXTVIEWS

Comment: Now what exception are you getting

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
TextView[] tv = new TextView[len];
        for (int i = 0; i <len; i++) 
        {
            tv[i] = new TextView(MainActivity1.this);
            tv[i].setText(mobileArray[i]);
            tv[i].setPadding(50, 50, 0, 0);
            tv[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF000000"));
            rl.addView(tv[i]);

        }
```

Comment: it seems like duplicate of my answer

Comment: We are posting answer at same time so i have seen your answer after posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code-

```
final int N = 10; // total number of textviews to add
final TextView[] tv = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // create a new textview
    final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
    // set some properties of rowTextView or something
    rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);
    // add the textview to the linearlayout
    rl.addView(rowTextView);
    // save a reference to the textview for later
    tv[i] = rowTextView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will help you

```
    int []a=new int[4];
    a[0]=1;
    a[1]=2;
    a[2]=3;
    a[3]=4;
    for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
        str4=str4+a.toString().valueOf(i)+"\n";
    }
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id."**Your layout ID**");
        TextView textDynamic = new TextView(this);
        textDynamic.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textDynamic.setText(str4);
        textDynamic.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        textDynamic.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        textDynamic.setTextScaleX(2);
        textDynamic.setTextSize(20);
        textDynamic.isClickable();
        textDynamic.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        rl.addView(textDynamic);
```